# Isolate BotFramework NodeJS Bot with LUIS into own library

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I want to isolate my bot, which uses BotFramework and LUIS, into it's own library and import it into the app.js. I followed the tutorials and examples on the BotFramework GitHub but it's getting me nowhere. Once I put the bot with LUIS dialogues into it's own file and export it, it never reaches out to LUIS:

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');

//Import our libraries
var profileDialogue = require('../dialogues/profileDialogue');

//=========================================================
// Bot Setup
//=========================================================

// Create chat bot
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(null, null, 'changeName');

// Add locale tools library to bot
bot.library(profileDialogue.createLibrary());

// Export createLibrary() function
exports.createLibrary = function() {
    return bot.clone();
}

var model = URL;
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(model);
var dialog = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [recognizer] });

//=========================================================
// Bots Dialogs
//=========================================================

bot.dialog('/changeName', dialog);

bot.dialog('change name', [
    function(session, args, next) {
        console.log(args);
        if (args.score > 0.5) {
            profileDialogue.profile(session);
        }
    },
    function(session, results) {
        session.send('Ok... Changed your name to %s', session.userData.name);
    }
]);
```

This code only works if it exists in the app.js file that node calls on, never when I want to isolate it for use in other bots.

Here is my app.js:

```
var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');

//Import our libraries
var changeName = require('./bots/changeName');

//=========================================================
// Bot Setup
//=========================================================

// Setup Restify Server
var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function() {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
});

// Create chat bot
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);

server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

//=========================================================
// Bots Dialogs
//=========================================================

bot.dialog('/', [function(session, args, next) { session.send("I don't understand") }]);

// Add locale tools library to bot
bot.library(changeName.createLibrary());
```

How can I achieve this properly? Am I not thinking about this the right way?

**UPDATE**

I was able to isolate the LUIS bot by using a different syntax (bot.dialog teamed up with triggerAction):

```
bot.dialog('/changeName', [
    function(session, args, next) {
        if (args && args.intent && args.intent.score && args.intent.score > 0.5) {
            console.log(args);
            profileDialog.profile(session);
        }
    },
    function(session, results) {
        session.send('Ok... Changed your name to %s', session.userData.name);
    }
]).triggerAction({
    matches: 'change name',
    intentThreshold: .50
});
```

The last remaining issue that I have is that the parent app.js NEEDS to have the LUIS endpoint, it doesn't matter if my child bot has it or not. Any additional ideas?

Comment: Is the top block of code the content of './bots/changeName' or is the content of your original unseparated bot? You seem to be creating the bot instance twice? I.e. two calls to builder.UniversalBot? You'll need to using RequireJS's module.export to export a function from the library you are including, and pass the bot instance created in your server into that function.

Comment: I'm a little new to the framework so I'm not sure if I am creating it twice or not. However, when I do export the bot itself I get the same errors using this: module.exports = { bot };

My intention is to be able to import multiple LUIS enabled bots, each with there own LUIS endpoint app, into a single location to build out my own framework and make the code easier to maintain. From what I can tell my biggest issue is with syntax, but I'm even sure if botframework supports this type of thinking in NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code will isolate the bot and allow it to be called into an app.js file, using LUIS:

```
bot.dialog('/changeName', [
    function(session, args, next) {
        if (args && args.intent && args.intent.score && args.intent.score > 0.5) {
            console.log(args);
            profileDialog.profile(session);
        }
    },
    function(session, results) {
        session.send('Ok... Changed your name to %s', session.userData.name);
    }
]).triggerAction({
    matches: 'change name',
    intentThreshold: .50
});
```